# Can I duplicate a trigger with my new spreadsheet?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a new client template that I want to keep from being filled out prior to being duplicated. I've set a trigger to run a duplication and renaming function for the file when the file is opened.

```
function newRecord(){ 
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var scheck = sheet.getName();
  if (scheck=='#New Client Record'){
  var file = DriveApp.getFilesByName('#New Client Record').next();
  file.setName('New Client')
  file.makeCopy('#New Client Record');
  }
}
```

This checks to see that the file is the correct file before proceeding, changes the name of the template and then duplicates the file and renames it the old template name. I configured it in this way so that when we start filling out the data right away while we're talking on the phone with a client, we aren't sullying our original template which remains pristine. It works nicely except that the trigger from file #1 doesn't transfer to file #2 which takes on the new identity of the original template.

So my question is - can I duplicate the trigger as well? Or is there script that can open the duplicate file and close the template file to protect my form?

EDIT: I threw a bit more at this last night and tried to add an install trigger with limited effect (I probably sound like a boomer talking about smoking the drugs with this - I'm not a programmer and have only a rudimentary vocabulary for script). I added the following function, which is transferring, but does not seem consistent in its functionality (excusing the pun).

```
function createSpreadsheetOpenTrigger() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  ScriptApp.newTrigger('newRecord')
      .forSpreadsheet(ss)
      .onOpen()
      .create();
}
```

Thanks for any assistance any of you can provide on this. I've stumbled my way this far on my own with the archives, but I've finally gotten myself stuck.

Comment: Can you add in more detail as to precisely how the workflow should work. Who should have edit/read capability after the file is duplicated? Who should be the owner? You can't duplicate tirggers by making a copy of a document but you can install a trigger programatically. Then again, you could just pass a link that will automatically create a copy of a document...

Comment: Sure! We have a small team (3 people) with shared access to the client drive. All parties have full access to view/edit the documents. Within the client drive is a #New Client Record that sits atop all the other client records listed alphabetically. Our problem was that when we get a call and start putting people's information into the new record, we were so focused on the conversation, we'd forget to duplicate and we'd sully our template. I'm trying to automate that. I've added a trigger install on the edit above, but I'm still not getting full functionality. Thanks for helping!

Comment: How complex is the new client record? You could potentially create a Google form and have an `onFormSubmit` trigger that will create a new document with the details filled out. Or to have even more control you could code the form and whatever else you like in HTML and JavaScript and serve it via an Apps Script webapp. Do those sound like viable alternatives?

Comment: They do sound like viable alternatives. The google form design is a bit clunky, but it's for internal use only and it could hold us over until we get something more sophisticated. So if I understand correctly, we can set up a form and then have the form create the copy and rename function upon  its submission of its entries into the designated cell fields? That sounds like it would kill 2 birds with 1 stone. Now to figure out how that all works...

Comment: What kind of document is the new client record? Sheet or Doc? Do you have a sample template you could share? That way I can show you a simple example as an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### How to get a form to create a new sheet with values from a template

Here is a quick example of how to carry this out. What you need to see this example in action:

- A template sheet that looks like this:
  [image: Template Sheet]
- A form that will have 3 "Short answers" that are required.

  - Client Name
  - Phone
  - Email
- A standalone script (Drive Web app > New > More > Google Apps Script).
- A folder into which all the newly created sheets will go.

At the top of the script (outside any function) you can define 3 global variables with the appropriate IDs:

```
const FORM_ID = ...
const TEMPLATE_ID = ...
const CLIENT_FOLDER_ID = ...
```

First, to set up an `onFormSubmit` trigger, you can do this by running the following function **only once**.

```js
function createTrigger(){
  const form = FormApp.openById(FORM_ID)
  ScriptApp.newTrigger("formSubmitReceiver")
    .forForm(form)
    .onFormSubmit()
    .create()
}
```

After which comes the main function that will:

1. Receive the `formSubmit` event and create a range of values from it.
2. In this example, it will generate a `followUpDate` that will be 7 days from the submission of the form.
3. Create a copy of the template file.
4. Fill the range `B1:B4` with the relevant info.

Resulting in a new spreadsheet:

[image]

```js
function formSubmitReceiver(e){
  const itemResponses = e.response.getItemResponses()

  const values = itemResponses.map( itemResponse => [itemResponse.getResponse()] )
  
  const followUpDate = new Date()
  followUpDate.setDate(followUpDate.getDate() + 7)
  values.push([followUpDate])

  const newFile = DriveApp.getFileById(TEMPLATE_ID).makeCopy()
  const parentFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById(CLIENT_FOLDER_ID)
  newFile.moveTo(parentFolder)
  newFile.setName(values[0][0])

  const newId = newFile.getId()

  const newSpreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById(newId) 
  const sheet = newSpreadsheet.getSheetByName("Sheet1");
  const range = sheet.getRange("B1:B4")
  range.setValues(values)
}
```

Depending on how complex you make your form, and what type of questions you choose (i.e multiple choice etc) this can get more complicated but hopefully it will give you a good idea of how to get something like this working. The simplest way is just to use "Short Answers" as this will just return a string. Also remember to make the questions "Required" if you don't want to handle empty values. Again, this all depends on how exactly you want to implement it and the complexity of the information involved!

#### References and Further Reading

- [`FormResponse`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/forms/form-response)
- [`getItemResponses()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/forms/form-response#getItemResponses())
- [`ItemResponse`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/forms/item-response)
- [`getFileById(id)`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/drive-app#getFileById(String))
- [`makeCopy()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/file.html#makeCopy())